# Referring to session-based data in a Mongoose virtual attribute

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a Mongoose model that holds Places. Each *place* has a lat/lng. I can define a Mongoose [virtual attribute](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/virtuals.html) called *distance* that would be used to sort Places in ascending order. What's the best way to refer to the user's location information (let's assume it's stored in a session variable for now) from inside the *distance* virtual attribute?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  Virtual attributes of Place should only refer to other properties of Place, not data in the session.

Comment: @JohnnyHK You're right -- I'm asking for a virtual attribute that depends on something that isn't a property of Place. Is that possible? Even if it is possible, is using a virtual attribute the best way of implementing it?

Comment: No, for anything involving external data I think you'd want to add a [method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/methods-statics.html) to the schema instead.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thanks for your answer. Using a method is definitely a better approach!

Comment: Glad it helped.  I'll add that as an answer so we can close out the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything involving external data, adding a [method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/methods-statics.html) to the schema would be a better choice than a virtual property.

Comment: but how do you call the method on a collection?

Answer (score 0):

I'm solving a similar issue. The problem is that methods are fine if you want perform an operation on a single value but I'm retrieving a list and want to inject a new virtual field into every record in the list - but use session data to generate the field.  to do this **safely** (avoiding globals), I think I'll need to use a [QueryStream](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#querystream_QueryStream) and inject the new field using an [ArrayFormatter](https://gist.github.com/1403797) that takes the session variables as constructor parameters.

This also looks like a job for LINQ so another approach might be to use one of the ports of LINQ to JS.

Answer (score -2):

If you sill prefer to use virtuals, you can store user location info in NodeJs globals. For example this code may be set after user login:

```
global.user_location = user.location;
```

Comment: I wonder if using globals might be a little risky given that the server may be processing multiple user requests concurrently.  You may be able to get away with it but if your task is pending a callback, I suspect that a different user's location may end up in the global.